# Proper way to use executor service multi-threading in web server?

Tags: multithreading, server, webserver, threadpool, executorservice

I have a web server that is run by a fleet of 50 hosts. One request to the server can result in 10 subsequent network calls, all of which can be done in parallel.

My idea is to create an executor service thread pool with 10 threads, so that each host can make the network calls in parallel.

However, there seems to be a problem with this. What if I get 1000 requests at once? And suppose a single host is tasked with 20 requests at the same time? Does this mean that the host will only have 10 threads available, and thus all 20 requests will compete with each other for the 10 threads? This seems WORSE than without thread pooling, in which case each request lives on its own thread and there's effectively 20 threads running at once.

Thus, it appears as if executor service is very dangerous in this situation, and has potential to actually make my application slower when in spiky volume. Am  I understanding the situation correctly? If so, what is a way to solve it? Should I have each request CREATE the 10 threads manually, rather than attempting to share from a pool and introduce that entanglement between different requests?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be conflating thread pooling to mean easier thread creation. But, its primary aim to reduce the thread requirements of an application, because threads get reused. So, if the first request ends up starting 10 threads, when the second request comes in, some of them may be available to be reused. So, the second request may not end up creating another 10 additional threads, but maybe 5. And the third request may not create any new thread at all. So, based on this, at a time, your service may need a thread-pool with only 15 threads. The advantage of the thread-pool in this case is these 15 threads will get created shortly after the requests start coming in, and will get reused till it dies, and your application, its runtime, and the underlying OS will not waste time creating and destroying threads, allocating stacks for them, etc.

Comment: "So, the second request may not end up creating another 10 additional threads, but maybe 5" The second request won't create any, it will use what is available in the pool of 10, which were created at application startup

Comment: You are right if the pool size is 10. Since you are debating whether to create 10 requests per request, it seems like you are willing to create more threads, meaning increase the pool size.